# asp.net mvc nerddinner question linq to entities join question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am working on a website similar to nerddinner. Is it possible to perform similar join
using Linq to entities what is done with linq to sql in nerddinner.
I am posting the codes below.

```
public IQueryable<Dinner> FindByLocation(float latitude, float longitude) {
        var dinners = from dinner in FindUpcomingDinners()
                      join i in db.NearestDinners(latitude, longitude) 
                      on dinner.DinnerID equals i.DinnerID
                      select dinner;

        return dinners;
    }
```

I want to replace this codes with linq to entities implementation.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: Where is your question?  Are you trying to find a replacement for db.NearestDinners?  Please explain what you are exposing with EF, and what SPs are available.

Comment: I want to use all the functions and procs used in the existing nerdinner application.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just look for where they intersect like:

```
FindUpcomingDinners().Intersect(db.NearestDinners(latitude, longitude)).ToList();
```

I am not sure what `FindUpcomingDinners` returns but the easiest would be to have two functions that return `IEnumerables` for `FindUpcomingDinners` and `NearestDinners` and then just get the intersect of the two lists.

Eg:

```
List<Dinner> upcomingDinners = FindUpcomingDinners();
List<Dinner> nearestDinners = NearestDinners(latitude, longitude);

List<Dinner> result = upcomingDinners.Intersect(nearestDinners).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Kelsey
but i get the folowing error
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Regards

Comment: @Parminder were you able to figure this out? If this answer helped you don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.